# Any way to remove points outlying shape in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am to map a plot of an area and then plot points over it (given by Easting and Northing). However, I found out that there are certain mistakes in the data entered for Easting and Northing resulting in some outlying points, and ggplot (which I am using) tends to reshape the map in order to fit the outlying points.

Is there any quick way to fix this issue? I do not know of any except to identify and correct the points manually. I am using shape files from the Ordnance survey.

Here is the screen-shot. The image does not appear to be skewed. However, upon comparison with other images, the differences become apparent.

[image]

Comment: You could subset your points data.frame before hand... the package `splancs` has a nice function `inout` that gives boolean of points in a polygon if you don't want to write the function yourself!

Comment: Ah! I had not known of the package at all. Thank you for bringing it to my attention! I will test it and let readers here know. Thank you!

Comment: If you know how to filter your data logically you can use the `subset` fuction: `subset(mydata, var.a < 45 & var.b > 23 & etc)`